# Exception during file upload using HttpClient

Tags: http, dotnet-httpclient

I am uploading large files using:

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
StreamContent imageContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(filename));
imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename));
content.Add(imageContent, "files", filename);
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

If the content exceeds the limits the kestrel server can handle it returns a "500" response. However, the client code above raises an exception during the PostAsync call: "A task was canceled., ".

Am I doing something wrong? How can I get the response message, i.e. the 500 message?

Comment: look at the inner exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, indeed. It say Timeout and that's what it was. Great!